# Drawing custom view using Android

Tags: android

I am drawing a custom view in my application which basically takes arguments(XML) as the text to display and then keeps on rotating it infinitely.

While I was making this control I had a few doubts which I want to ask:

- I have made 2 of my stylable attributes which I have declared in the `attrs.xml` file. These attributes are to set the width and the width of the circle used in my control. These values I would use in the ondraw method and the onmeasure method. I ran my program by declaring just these but there was an error which asked me to put `android:width and android:height` attributes. My question is why would I need those if I am already using my custom attributes to define the height and the width of my view
- I am coding on a mac. Now when I was making my `attrs.xml` file, to get the autocomplete list which we usually get by ctrl+space was not showing up. Why is that. For e.g., i wanted to know what values can I give the format attribute of my custom attribute that like I am demostrating in the following: 
  `<attr name ="somename" format="value I wanted to find out through autocomplete">` . Why is the autocomplete not popping up? It does pop up when I am making a.java file.
- In my `ondraw()` method I wanted to draw a circle. Now for this I would require the co-ordinates of the center of the circle. So what I do is put 0, 0. But this is not correct. I want the circle to be at the center of the parent view it is in. So if my view is in a hierarchy I want it to respect that. I want to give the co-ordinates relative to the parent view. What is happeining right now is that it is being drawn at the top left corner of my screen. This is what I don't want. What do I do to achieve this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> why would I need those if I am already using my custom attributes to define the height and the width of my view?

This is because Android needs to know how and where to put your view in the layout.  You can implement your view to make use of your custom height/width requirements by overriding [View.onMeasure()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onMeasure%28int,%20int%29) to return your own size parameters.  You can then just set `android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"` in your layout file.

> Why is the autocomplete not popping up? It does pop up when I am making a.java file.

Autocomplete and autodoc implementation for Android xml files is shaky at best, so it's not really surprising that it doesn't work.  I'm not aware of a fix and AFAIK it's an IDE bug.

> In my ondraw() method I wanted to draw
>   a circle. Now for this I would require
>   the co-ordinates of the center of the
>   circle. So what I do is put 0, 0. But
>   this is not correct. I want the circle
>   to be at the center of the parent view
>   it is in. So if my view is in a
>   hierarchy I want it to respect that. I
>   want to give the co-ordinates relative
>   to the parent view. What is happeining
>   right now is that it is being drawn at
>   the top left corner of my screen. This
>   is what I don't want. What do I do to
>   achieve this?

If you implemented onMeasure() correctly, the coordinates relative to parent should be taken care of already.  To get the center of your view use the following code:

```
void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
{
int centerX = this.getWidth() / 2;
int centerY = this.getHeight()) / 2;
//..draw code here
}
```

**Edit**
Here's an example with source code that should help: http://mindtherobot.com/blog/272/android-custom-ui-making-a-vintage-thermometer/

Comment: thank you for you reply. Now when i am doing this.getWidth(), i do need to take care of what density i am working with, correct? In XML there is this great provision with dip so that i can hard code units, is there a similar way to do things via code?

Comment: Also when i talk about a canvas in the above method, that includes the whole screen, or the part of the screen in which my view lies?

Comment: @user590849 GetWidth handles the density already, provided you handle density properly in onMeasure().  Also, one suggestion I've seen is to call canvas.scale() in onDraw() and set the scale to 1.0 to 1.0 so that 1.0 is the width/height of the view.  Then all of your sizes are in terms of the actual view size.

Comment: ok. that is a good suggestion. But when you say that i have to handle this in the measure method, how do i do this. Actually i am unaware how to handle screen independence when i am doing via code. i am clear when doing it with XML.

Comment: @user590849 I think all the onMeasure dimmensions are in dip units, but am not sure.  Check out this example with source code for further suggestions. http://mindtherobot.com/blog/272/android-custom-ui-making-a-vintage-thermometer/